# Can any one explain me this error ClassCastException occured : java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

Can any one explain me this error ClassCastException occured : java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String? Below is the code that i had written to fetch the data

```
 List<AdsOnUIRenderdata> ren2 = AdsOnUIRenderdata.find("select distinct a.appName from AdsOnUIRenderdata a").fetch();
         long ads=0;


            for(int i =0;i<ren2.size();i++)
            {

              ads =AdsOnUIRenderdata.count("userFeedback='INTERESTED' and appName =?",ren2.get(i).appName );

            }
```

In the above code first I am fetching the appname from the database and based up on that appname again I am querying.so,can any one resolve this problem please.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning a String collection, and not the AdsOnUIRenderdata collection.

In this case, either you change your query to select the whole class, like this:

```
List<AdsOnUIRenderdata> ren2 = AdsOnUIRenderdata.find("select distinct a from AdsOnUIRenderdata a").fetch();
```

Or you change the collection receiving you query results, like this:

```
List<String> ren2 = AdsOnUIRenderdata.find("select distinct a.appName from AdsOnUIRenderdata a").fetch();
```